# How can the TypeText delay in Watin be reduced?

Tags: c#, watin

How does one reduce the delay between keypresses in the `TypeText` method of Watin? Is there a better way if I want to "instantaneously" type some text?

Comment: Just to be clear, "blog-type" posts are not recommended. Asking-then-answering questions is not really the purpose of this site. However, "answered my own question" is just fine.

Comment: @drachenstern: I did indeed answer my own question, and decided to post it in case someone else ran into the same issue.

Comment: I have removed watir tag since the question is not related to it.

Comment: @drachenstern: According to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question." In this particular case, it was done correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to `.ClickNoWait()` on the element, and then just set its `.Value` property.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can I see an example in use? I'm having trouble executing.

Answer (score 7):

I know its a bit late but I might as well share this bit of info for others having the same problem who land here especially considering you asked for an example.

```
IE browser = new IE();

browser.TextField("UserName").Value = "admin";
browser.TextField("Password").Value = "pass123";
```

Have fun. [Here](http://blog.dbtracer.org/2010/08/05/speed-up-typing-text-with-watin/) is a nice post on an alternative way which is where I found this some time back.

Answer (score 2):

```
    LoginPage LoginPage = Browser.Page<LoginPage>();

    string UserName = ConstVars.UserName;
    string Password = ConstVars.Password;

    if (LoginPage.UserNameTextField.GetAttributeValue("value") != UserName)
    {
        LoginPage.UserNameTextField.SetAttributeValue("value", UserName);
    }
    if (LoginPage.PasswordTextField.GetAttributeValue("value") == null)
    {
        LoginPage.PasswordTextField.SetAttributeValue("value", Password);
    }
    LoginPage.ClickLoginButton();
```

For me, simply setting the value attribute for the text field worked, but it could depend on how the page is coded.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, and just clicking on the text field and setting the value was causing test failures because our ASP.NET WebForms application has validators that execute when the `change` event fires. Here is the source code for an Extension to WatiN:

```
using WatiN.Core;

namespace Project.Extensions
{
    public static class WatinExtensions
    {
        public static void TypeTextFaster(this TextField textfield, string value)
        {
            textfield.Value = value;
            textfield.Change();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have event handlers that get triggered when the user clicks on the `textfield`, just add `textfield.Click()` or `textfield.ClickNoWait()` before setting the value.

Remember the `using Project.Extensions;` line at the beginning of your code to include the WatiN extensions.

Now you can call the extension method:

```
TextField field = browser.TextField("id");

field.TypeTextFaster("the text to type");
```